# Is it possible to replicate condition at planck time after big bang by smashing 2 protons really hard?

Tags: big-bang, large-hadron-collider

Because we need to achieve really really high temperature to mimick the condition just planck time after big bang, so suppose we can accelerate 2 protons at extremely close to speed of light and let them collide with one another at super high energy. Is this enough to replicate condition planck time after big bang? Is this engineering issue or are there some laws of physics which forbid us from achieving it?

Comment: It's likely to require an accelerator as long as a galaxy.